# should i use django's many-to-many option?

Tags: django, many-to-many, self-join

Django newb here, working off the django polls tutorial and trying to add a model that'll keep track of the poll results:

```
# Create your models here.
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    numChoices = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Session_results(models.Model):
    sessionKey=models.ForeignKey(Session)
    questionAsked = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    answerChosen=models.ForeignKey(Choice)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sessionKey
```

The use case is that I basically have a list of questions (Poll model), a list of choices where each choice maps to a question (Choice model), and I want to keep a list of sessions, where I can keep track of what questions a user has answered (Session_results model). Ultimately, I'd like to compare and do stuff with sessions. For example if session X answered questions 1 and 2, find out what other sessions also answered questions 1 and 2, which in my mind would involve a self join in sql. 
So if that's my goal, should I be using the many-to-many? I was thinking about replacing a line in the Session_results model:

```
questionAsked = models.ManyToManyField(Poll)
```

After i put this line in and run python manage.py sql polls, I see that django automatically created a join table for me, but that table doesn't seem to be serving my future needs.
I read the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ page, and it didn't seem to answer my question.
Also given what I want to do, would i be using raw sql queries?

thanks!!

Comment: Since you don't say what your question or your "future needs" are, this is impossible to answer. You might want to look at the section on [extra data with m2m relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) though.

Comment: sorry, it was in the middle of my paragraph:  For example if session X answered questions 1 and 2, find out what other sessions also answered questions 1 and 2, and then if question 1 answered by session X equaled question 1 answered by session Y. and do that for more than just two questions.

Comment: Been using Django for years and I very rarely use manytomany fields preferring to define one to many relationships myself and making it easier to extend the link file in future.